# How to temporarily disable auto-upgrade without a Nix rebuild?

Tags: nixos, nix

While on a metered connection it would be *really* handy to be able to disable `system.autoUpgrade` without having to rebuild the entire system and use up several GB/days/$$$ worth of credit. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going from the [documentation](https://search.nixos.org/options?channel=21.05&show=system.autoUpgrade.enable&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=system.autoUpgrade.enable) via [the code](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/nixos-21.05/nixos/modules/tasks/auto-upgrade.nix) and finally to `systemctl | grep nixos-upgrade` there's both a timer and a service. It looks like the timer simply starts the service. I've run `sudo systemctl stop nixos-upgrade.timer`, and now the "Trigger" line says "n/a" rather than a datetime / interval. I hope that is enough.

Comment: That's going to be enough until the next reboot.